# Is there an icon set for displaying "All", "Some", and "None" states?

Tags: icon

Is there an icon set for displaying "All", "Some", and "None" states?

For example, an icon for "All categories", one for "Some categories", and one for "No categories".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about circles with either no fill, half filled, or fully filled to represent none, some, and all, respectively.

[ something along these lines ... ]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The only "standardized" set I can think of is how [check boxes](https://www.google.com/search?q=checkbox+states&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi) are often handled to show none, some, or all:

[image: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC147693.png]

Comment: I've always found this convention incredibly counterintuitive: the "partially selected" boxes are completely filled in, while the fully selected ones only have a small mark in them. I'd find almost _any_ other symbol for a partial selection (like, say, a + in the square to show that you have to expand it to see what's selected and what isn't) more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hand: five fingers for all, 2 or 3 fingers for some, and a fist closed for none

Comment: Body parts in icons, especially finger gestures, should be prevented at all costs (see https://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/3.0/icons-design.html.en). Quote: «...A prime source of offensive imagery is various body parts in a number of different configurations. Aside from offensive gestures with the hands, arms or fingers; body parts that are considered "clean" in one culture (such as eyes), will be considered tasteless or gross to another (such as a nose)...»